# Add Paypal sdk external js as an internal js file in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm currently including the PayPal JS SDK in index.html with `<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=...`

To render the buttons, in the .ts file, I'm following up with this code:

```
declare var paypal: any;

export class BuyComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("paypal", { static: true }) paypalElement: ElementRef;
  paypal
      .Buttons({
        ...
```

I tried saving it as `paypal.js` in `assets/js` folder and then in `angular.json`, I added

```
"scripts": [
      ...,
      "src/assets/js/paypal.js"
  ]
```

but this gives me error as `ReferenceError: paypal is not defined`

How can I include this external js as internal file in my Angular code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paypal sdk js file should always be sourced and loaded externally by each client (browser) on page load

There is no support for a stashed copy

Comment: Okay. So, is the js file loaded every time not same? I was thinking for this so that I don't have to load file externally again and again

Comment: It's subject to change. Each client browser will cache it for a max of 6 hours.

Comment: Okay. Just one more thing, can you point me to a doc or something which refers the same?

Comment: All developer.paypal.com documentation and answers from PayPal say to use the script tag with an absolute path.  The HTTP response header of "cache-control: public, max-age=21600" is set on script load; you can examine it in the dev tools Network tab or however you like.

Comment: Okay. I checked in doc [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/troubleshoot/performance/#) as well. Thank you!